# How can I run a single function on the opening of a Java 8 stream, before any other intermediate methods?

Tags: java, java-8, handler, java-stream

I'm honestly not even sure that this is possible yet, outside of adjacent lines of code. However, I thought I would check with the community.

Java 8 allows for the management of its Collections via the Stream API. Where we used to need external iterations, now we can simply use:

```
<Collection>.stream().forEach([expression]);
```

This is great when I'm trying to format a large collection quickly, and, say, output it to a BufferedOutputStream or some other target. What I need to do is place a little info on what it is that I'm writing, next to it. So far, the best I can come up with is something like:

```
labelData();
firstNames.stream().sequential().forEach(sz -> reportData(sz));
```

Whereas, it would be really nice if I could so something like:

```
firstNames.stream().sequential().
    .onOpen(labelData())
    .forEach(sz->reportData(sz));
```

I know that it's possible to set up an on-close method with BaseStream.onClose(Runnable closeHandler). Does such a method exist for open?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: The first example is shorter, simpler, faster and clearer as to what it is doing. Can you explain what is "nicer" about the second example?

Comment: Well, the example is somewhat constructed, and generally it's a question of instance. However, there are cases in which I would prefer to preface my output with a label or even a functional token, and I much prefer to use stream API when at all possible.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I've edited both for clarity. Hopefully that will help.

Comment: Then you will have to use `collect`. Your task is similar to what [`Collectors.joining`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) does (note the prefix parameter). Have a look at its backend, [`StringJoiner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what map() is for.

```
firstNames.map(e -> addLabel(e)).forEach(this::reportData);
```

map() is an intermediate operation that performs a transformation on each element as it is processed.

For instance, the code:

```
Stream.of("One","Two", "Three", "Four");
        .map(e -> "Number " + e)
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

will output:

```
Number One
Number Two
Number Three
Number Four
```

If you really just want to write out something before the stream... just do so. Calling it inside the stream is a lot less efficient anyway. if you need to only write it out if the stream contains elements, you can do something like this:

```
package stream;

public class OneTimePrinter {
    private boolean shouldPrint = true;

    public void print(Object o){
        if (shouldPrint){
            System.out.println(o);
            shouldPrint = false;
        }
    }
}
```

And then use that OneTimePrinter class in a *peek()* operation:

```
OneTimePrinter printer1 = new OneTimePrinter();
Stream.of("Five","Six", "Seven", "Eight")
.peek((e) -> printer1.print("TEST OUTPUT:\n------------"))
.map(e -> "Number " + e)
.forEach(System.out::println);  

OneTimePrinter printer2 = new OneTimePrinter();
Stream.of()
.peek((e) -> printer2.print("TEST OUTPUT:\n------------"))
.map(e -> "Number " + e)
.forEach(System.out::println);
```

which will output:

```
TEST OUTPUT:
------------
Number Five
Number Six
Number Seven
Number Eight
```

It's still way easier and way more efficient to just call your labelData() function before you do the forEach(). Just out of curiosity, I came up with three different ways to do this, and tested them all with a million element stream using the following code:

First, a new type of Collector which performs an action and returns the original stream:

```
public interface StreamOpenCollector<T> extends Collector<T, Object, Stream<T>> {   
    static <T> Collector<T, Object, Stream<T>> onOpen(Object arg, Consumer<Object> consumer){
        return Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), (list) -> {
            consumer.accept(arg);
            return list.stream();
        });
    }   
}
```

And the aforementioned OneTimePrinter, and then the test class:

```
public class StreamOnOpenTest {
    LinkedHashMap<String, Long> times = new LinkedHashMap<String, Long>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StreamOnOpenTest test = new StreamOnOpenTest();

        test.addTime("SkipMethod", test.time(IntStream.range(0, 1000000).mapToObj(e -> "" + e), (stream) -> {
            stream
                .skip(StreamOnOpenTest.labelData())
                .map(e -> "Number " + e)
                .forEach(System.out::println);              
        }));


        test.addTime("PeekMethod", test.time(IntStream.range(0, 1000000).mapToObj(e -> "" + e), (stream) -> {
            OneTimePrinter printer = new OneTimePrinter();
            stream
                .peek((e) -> printer.print("TEST OUTPUT:\n------------"))
                .map(e -> "Number " + e)
                .forEach(System.out::println);          
        }));

        test.addTime("CollectMethod", test.time(IntStream.range(0, 1000000).mapToObj(e -> "" + e), (stream) -> {
            stream
                .collect(StreamOpenCollector.onOpen("TEST OUTPUT:\n------------", System.out::println))
                .map(e -> "Number " + e)
                .forEach(System.out::println);      
        }));    

        test.printTimes();
    }

    private void addTime(String key, long value){
        times.put(key, value);
    }

    private void printTimes() {
        System.out.println("------------\n------------\n");
        times.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println("For " + key + ", time was " + value + " milliseconds"));
    }

    private long time(Stream<String> stream, Consumer<Stream<String>> consumer){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        consumer.accept(stream);
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return endTime - startTime;
    }

    private static int labelData(){
        System.out.println("TEST OUTPUT:");
        System.out.println("------------");
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The final result of this over three runs was:

```
--RUN 1--
For SkipMethod, time was 3479 milliseconds
For PeekMethod, time was 3574 milliseconds
For CollectMethod, time was 3593 milliseconds

--RUN 2--
For SkipMethod, time was 3603 milliseconds
For PeekMethod, time was 3684 milliseconds
For CollectMethod, time was 3718 milliseconds

--RUN 3--
For SkipMethod, time was 3534 milliseconds
For PeekMethod, time was 3540 milliseconds
For CollectMethod, time was 3606 milliseconds
```

As you can see, the skip method was consistently quicker, but not enough to worry about unless you're processing billions of items in your stream.

Comment: Thank you, that is exactly what I'm looking for. I'm well aware of the efficiency issues, this was chiefly a theoretical question, and your answer is sublime.

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
labelData();
firstNames.forEach(this::reportData);
```

Sometimes the simpler answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered, *.map()* is what you are looking for.

But I want to point out something that I think needs to: *labelData()* is doing a side effect on *firstNames* (it looks like it is a field / global variable).

Side effects to me are not good in functional programming because they introduce state. And that is one of the reason streams come for, to avoid state.

Also it sounds weird that you are not collecting the stream at the end but reporting on each element. But this is probably due to the simplification for your example.

Comment: labelData() is purely a notational shortcut. Think of it as psuedo-code. It is not an actual method, just a predecessor before report on an arbitrary stream.

Comment: `firstNamesLabeled = labelData(firstNames);

firstNamesLabeled.stream().forEach(sz -> reportData(sz));`
I think this shows you more why you need a map. If `labelData()` is constructed in that way, like a pure function and not with side effect, the code becomes `firstNames.stream().map(f -> labelData(f)).forEach(sz -> reportData(sz));` Also note that the `sequential()` call is not useful in this case, every stream you create is sequential by default.